# Is it possible to just print the string that was passed into the Scheme macro?

Tags: macros, scheme, guile, r5rs

I am working on a language translator in guile scheme, and need to handle the basic case, where you're trying to convert a single word.

```
(define var 5)
(translate var)
```

This should return the string `var` and not the number `5`.
How do I do this using R5RS Scheme macros (the `define-syntax` style)?

Edit:
I'm translating from Scheme to Coffeescript.

Comment: I bet if you provided more details about what kind of language translator you were working on, you'd get much more useful help. What are you translating from and into, and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(define-syntax translate
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ v) 'v]))
```

And if you want a string:

```
(define-syntax translate
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ v) (symbol->string 'v)]))
```

Hopefully Guile's compiler is smart enough to fold the resulting expression so it essentially becomes a constant string.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I meant that it should return an actual string (so that I can use (string-append) on it.

Comment: Would it be acceptable for you to wrap a use of a `symbol->string` around the `'v`?

Comment: This works with the symbol->string wrapping. Now I need to find a work around for bare numbers. Thank you.

Comment: @chustar: I updated it with `symbol->string`.  If you want to do something with number it would be similar in principle.

Comment: Thanks @EliBarzilay. I added an (if (?number 'v) (number->string 'v) (symbol->string 'v))) to handle the number situation. Thanks.

Comment: @chustar In that case, you'd be better off using `syntax-case`'s guards. Lemme post an example.

Comment: @chustar: But what about other kinds of syntax?  Sounds like you want some kind of `format` to just turn anything into a string.

Comment: @EliBarzilay I think I only need to worry about things that are numbers, and things that I can pretend are symbols (using `). Everything else (like lists and no one) would be parsed recursively.
I'll look into format just in case though.

Answer (score 4):

With `syntax-case` and its guard support:

```
(define-syntax translate
  (lambda (stx)
    (syntax-case stx ()
      [(_ v) (identifier? #'v)
       #'(symbol->string 'v)]
      [(_ v) (number? (syntax-e #'v))
       #'(number->string v)])))
```

(I've used square brackets for easy comparison with Eli's answer, however, it's not my usual style. ;-))

But if you're using `syntax-case`, then you can just as well do the conversion at the syntax level instead of producing code that does it at runtime:

```
(define-syntax translate
  (lambda (stx)
    (syntax-case stx ()
      [(_ v) (identifier? #'v)
       (datum->syntax stx (symbol->string (syntax->datum #'v)))]
      [(_ v) (number? (syntax-e #'v))
       (datum->syntax stx (number->string (syntax->datum #'v)))])))
```

The main thing here is that the macro code is now plain scheme, for example, you could abstract the common parts into a helper:

```
(define-syntax translate
  (lambda (stx)
    (define (rewrap convert x)
      (datum->syntax stx (convert (syntax->datum x))))
    (syntax-case stx ()
      [(_ v) (identifier? #'v) (rewrap symbol->string #'v)]
      [(_ v) (number? (syntax-e #'v)) (rewrap number->string #'v)])))
```

Along the same lines, if this macro is so simple, then there's no real need for `syntax-case`, other than pulling out the subexpression:

```
(define-syntax translate
  (lambda (stx)
    (syntax-case stx ()
      [(_ v) (let ([d (syntax->datum #'v)])
               (datum->syntax
                stx
                ((cond [(number? d) number->string]
                       [(symbol? d) symbol->string])
                 d)))])))
```

Note, BTW, that there is no magic in `syntax-case` -- and in the case of this simple pattern, you could just pull out the value yourself:

```
(define-syntax translate
  (lambda (stx)
    (let ([d (cadr (syntax->datum #'v))])
      (datum->syntax
       stx
       ((cond [(number? d) number->string]
              [(symbol? d) symbol->string])
        d)))))
```

There is some boilerplate stuff that `syntax-case` does that this last version loses:

- If you use the macro in an unexpected way like `(translate)` then this version will throw an error about `cadr` instead of a more comprehensible syntax error
- Similarly, if you use `(translate 1 2)` then this version will just silently ignore the `2` instead of an error.
- And if it's used with something that is neither an identifier nor a number (eg, `(translate (+ 1 2))`) then this will depend on the unspecified value that `cond` returns rather than throwing a syntax error.

Comment: I wanted to add: with a small modification, Chris's `syntax-case` macro can do a little more work at compile-time, so that even the `symbol->string` and `number->string` stuff doesn't occur at run-time.

Comment: Bah.  It makes little sense in doing *that*...  If you're going with `syntax-case` you can just as well to the conversions there, instead of expanding to code that does them.

Comment: @Eli: I agree. I just wanted to match your code (which I know works, because your posts are always high-quality :-)), so I don't have to bother testing mine. But I'll edit the code now.

Comment: Wow, this is more info than I've seen on the topic online all day. Thanks.

Comment: @chustar: Most of that info is from Eli. Thanks to him, indeed. :-D

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are useful enough already, but I thought I'd just point out that it's possible to generalize this technique in a very useful ways: macros to print out expressions and their results for debugging:

```
(define-syntax log-expr
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ expr)
     (let ((result expr))
       (write (quote expr))
       (display " evaluates to ")
       (write result)
       (newline)
       result))))
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for!